# Как динамически изменять время анимации Angular2?

Tags: angular2

Есть вот такая анимация.

```
 animations: [
trigger('flyInOut', [
  transition('void => *', [
    style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
    animate(2000)
  ]),
  transition('* => void', [
    animate(2000, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
  ])
])
```

Как динамически изменять время анимации ? `animate(2000)`

Answer (score 0):

В последних версиях появился сервис `AnimationBuilder`, вот пример работы с ним https://www.yearofmoo.com/2017/06/new-wave-of-animation-features.html#programmatic-animations-with-animationbuilder